# How to Add an item to ArrayList and Dictionary using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        myArray = new List<int>();
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary;

    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary
    {
        get { return myDictionary; }
    }

    private List<int> myArray;

    public List<int> MyArray
    {
        get { return myArray; }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var model = new MyClass();
    Type t = model.GetType();
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
    //Add items to MyArray and MyDictionary in this model According to the properties using reflection
}
```

I want to add items to MyArray and MyDictionary in this model According to the properties using reflection.
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dictProp = properties.Single(t => t.Name = "MyDictionary");
var myDict = (Dictionary<string,string>)dictProp.GetValue(model, null);
myDict.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");
```

Comment: Seems to be "myDict" does not contain a definition for "Add". If I understand the wrong.thx

Comment: @HuanFu sorry, I forgot to cast it to the right type - GetValue returns `object`.

Answer (score 0):

To add an Item to a `Generic.List<T>` you use the `Add` method

Example:

```
MyArray.Add(1);
```

For `Generic.Dictonary<T>` you also use the `Add` method, but supply 2 values, Key and Value

```
MyDictionary.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");
```

So you can just loop though your `PropertyInfo[]` and add whatever you need to your `List<T>` or `Dictionary<T>`

```
foreach(var prop in properties )
{
   MyArray.Add(a number from somewhere);

   MyDictionary("some key", "some value");
}
```

Comment: sorry, I only be allowed use the item.name in properties.   foreach(var item in properties) {if (item.name == "MyArray") {//add an number in this Array}}